# Running and integrating Django backend and Angular Frontend using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created an application with angular frontend and django rest framework based backend. 
I have created an image for both of them and they are running fine using docker.
The av-app-multistage container is the angular container and the server is the django backend.
[image]

To run this app I have to start both of them individually . How can i create some kind of script that automates this process. So that if I run the angular container it automatically runs the backend??

Here are my dockerfiles.
This is the docker file for django

```
FROM python:3.6

# The enviroment variable ensures that the python output is set straight
# to the terminal with out buffering it first
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# create root directory for our project in the container
RUN mkdir /app_service

# Set the working directory to /music_service
WORKDIR /app_service

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /music_service
ADD . /app_service/

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

this is the docker compose file for django

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: app_service
    volumes:
      - .:/app_service
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

This is the docker file for angular

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/movie-info-service /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start both of them in a single compose file as a stack.

Checkout `docker stack deploy` command

You can also write a compose file with those 2 services and you can also write them in a way so frontend depends on the backend.